# Ajax toolkit for manipulating tables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, tablelayout

(dismal response to previous question)

I'm building a website in PHP and I have tables presented that I need to allow the user to:

1. add new entry (only one at a time, which should appear as a new modal overlay)
2. delete multiple selected entries from
3. edit an existing entry (only one at one time, in a view similar to 1.)
4. re-arrange entries up and down. One by one is fine. Multiple / Grouping rearrangements are not not needed

What jQuery / js / anything toolkit would be the SIMPLEST to work with? (of course, I should be able to work with it in php).

I did try hacking away at: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/ but had a terrible time trying to get it to work on editing some existing data (had problem passing data to it).

Answer (score 1):

I could recommend you jqGrid. In my opinion it is the best current jQuery plugin, which support all you requirements and much more. The plugin is alive. You have a very good forum http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393 for your questions. Most of examples from the jqGrid documentation http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php for the server side are in PHP.

You can see possibilities of jqGrid on http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at dhtmlXgrid - AFAIK its not jquery based but I think it provides the front end functionality you're looking for.